# How to play physics in a specific frame

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am currently learning about the physics in blender. I have a sample blend file, the physics works well but it starts automatically in the first frame what i wanted is to play the animation in a specific frame like 10, 20, or so. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Rigid body cache in Scene panel, there you can set the start and end of simulation.

Comment: after setting? should i click the bake button?

Comment: No need to click it just set the start and end frames for simulation